# Exporting material files with obj

Tags: materials, export, shaders

I tried to export my blender file in obj format along with mtl file.
But when I reopened the obj file in a new blender folder it didn't have any material with it.
The model I made had only materials (I used shading with a complex node tree to make a PBR material) no texture applied to it. And it was also uv unwrapped.
I am actually trying to upload this file to cj traders. But I want upload it along with the PBR materials that I have used in it.
Is there any particular setting that I should have done.
Remember that I haven't used any image texture. It's only shading nodes to create the materials.
Kindly help

Comment: why export obj to open it in blender again? append it, then you will have your materials. obj, [(*as with most other exchange formats*)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures) doesnt care about materials, you at best get a very basic approximation of what you had on export.

Comment: 3D formats do not store the same kind of information. .Obj files cannot store blender's shaders. All you can hope for in such format is to bake the texture to an image or to maps that mimic the settings you have in blender, but then you would need to reconstruct the materials in other softwares.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information. So can you suggest what I should do to upload my models on websites like cj trader Or turbo squid. So that people downloading my files can get the same result(looks) as I did in my pc.